# Can not display this video mode ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, display

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 alongwith windows 10 on my pc. The installation process looked fairly troublefree. On grub bootloader after selecting ubuntu and entering my pass the next thing that comes up is
1.Analog input
Can not display this video mode
(With a black screen)
I am able to access it in the recovery mode and then going to normal boot from there but not from the main menu. Is there any solution to that?
I am using a old lcd btw
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: you need to add a bit more information,what graphics card do you have and what type of pc do you have.it sounds like you have a graphics driver problem.

Comment: Yeah it was a graphics card's driver problem. I installed the latest driver for my card in recovery mode and it worked

Comment: please make this as the answer and accept it as solved,this is to avoid this question popping up every week as unsolved and you might even gain some more reputation.